# To Fetch input text field value and adhere it to Subject of mail

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code in which i want to capture "subject" from input field and append it to "Subject" of "form" tag.
I am not getting how to use document.getElementById here.
Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="mailto:somebody@gmail.com?Subject=Internal Issues enctype="text/plain">

    <label for="Subject">Subject</label>
     <input type="text" id="Subject" name="Subject">
    </html>
    </body>
```

Comment: `document.getElementByid('subject').value`.....?

Comment: yeah after using "document.getElementByid('subject').value" how can i assign it to Subject in "mailto" option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here don't use method or type with form attribute and your input test must contains name="subject"

Try with,

```js
document.getElementById('sender').addEventListener("click", sendEmail);

function GetBody() {
  var body = "Assignee : " + document.getElementById('Assignee').value + '\n' + "Requester: " + document.getElementById('Requester').value + '\n';
  return body;
};

function sendEmail() {
  var email = 'someone@gmail.com';
  var body = GetBody();
  var subject = document.getElementById('subject').value;
  var mailto_link = 'mailto:' + email + '?subject=' + subject + '&body=' + encodeURIComponent(body);
  window.location.href = mailto_link;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div style="white-space:nowrap">
    <label for="Requester" style="padding-right:50px;">Requester*</label>
    <input type="text" id="Requester" name="Requester:" placeholder="Your Vuclip Mail Id..">
  </div>
  <div style="white-space:nowrap">
    <label for="Assignee" style="padding-right:57px;">Assignee*</label>
    <input type="text" id="Assignee" name="Assignee" placeholder="Whom you want to assign">
  </div>
  <div style="white-space:nowrap">
    <label for="subject" style="padding-right:57px;">Subject*</label>
    <input id="subject" name="subject " type="text" value="I have a suggestion" style="width: 870px; font-size: 18px;" />
  </div>
</form>
<button id="sender">Send email</button>
```

Comment: Hi
The above code works fine for me...but it works "onsubmit" but i need subject entered to appear on Subject column of mail by using other events such as onchange ...coz i have another event to call on submit...any help on this please

Comment: is it possible that you can share your html in jsfiddle so i can help

Comment: When i click on submit i am getting subject also in mail's body..i know if i remove name=subject it won't appear...but i need the text entered in subject box to appear on Subject of mail..
Please help

Comment: can anyone please help on this

Comment: here Requester is From and Assignee is To ?

Comment: Hi Priyal,
Sorry... Requester/Assignee fields does not matter here
Just want whatever we enter in subject field to "Subject" of mail...
any help is appreciated